# Origin of "cream" meaning "to defeat decisively"

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the verb *cream* meaning *to defeat someone*, such as in this example?

> We **creamed** them.

Comment: Etymonline has [meaning "to beat, thrash, wreck" is 1929, U.S. colloquial](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cream&searchmode=none).

Comment: Pratchett quote: "we are going to get cheesed - it's like creamed but harder and lasts longer" (Night Watch?)

Answer (score 15):

The Oxford English Dictionary writes that the relevant definition is:

> *transf*. To deal with vigorously and with success, esp. to beat or thrash; to defeat heavily, as in sporting contexts; to ruin or wreck (a motor vehicle, etc.). colloq. (orig. U.S.).

It was first used in 1929, by the Princeton Alumni Weekly:

> 1929    Princeton Alumni Weekly 24 May 981/1   Say, if he opens his mouth, I'll cream him.

Note that they write this use is *transf*--the OED uses this to mean [*transferred sense*](http://www.oed.com/public/abbreviations#t). That is, another meaning of the verb *cream* was applied to a new situation. The OED writes that the associated meaning of *cream* is applied to baking:

> a. To work (butter and sugar, yolk of eggs and sugar, etc.) into a creamy consistency.

This requires a fair amount of beating the butter and sugar together, and so the Princeton Alumni Weekly applied this action to a new situation.

Comment: +1 *Transf.* = transferred sense.

Comment: @Cerb--Thank you! I added a link to the OED list of abbreviations to my answer too.

Answer (score 8):

There is a procedure in cooking called "creaming butter" that involves beating the butter moderately hard for a long time. From a [cooking website](http://www.soscuisine.com/glossaire.php?sos_l=en):

> To beat one or more ingredients until the mixture is soft, homogeneous, and smooth, i.e. "creamy".

I always assumed that this was the basis of the metaphor "We creamed them", meaning "We beat them really, really well."